# Tabulator.js: Change the number of rows of the dropdown list when using the list editor

Tags: tabulator

Is it possible to change the number of displayed rows inside the dropdown-list when using the "list editor" with Tabulator.js (5.6)?
For me it looks like, that it is fixed to 8 rows...

```
{title:"Source", field:"source", width:200, editor:"list", headerFilter:"input", editable:editCheck, editorParams:{
  values:{
    "test1:"test1",
    "test2:"test2",
    "test3:"test3",
    "test4:"test4",
    "test5:"test5",
    "test6:"test6",
    "test7:"test7",
    "test8:"test8",
    "test9:"test9",
    "test10:"test10",
    "test11:"test11",
    "test12:"test12",
  },
  maxWidth:false,
  allowEmpty:true,
  listOnEmpty:true,
  freetext:true,
  multiselect:false,
  autocomplete:true,
}},
```

Comment: The list has a max height of 200px: `.tabulator-edit-list { max-height: 200px; }`.  You can change this value in your css file to overwrite it.